# Automatically set PostGIS/QGIS style to a layer

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I have a plugin for my users which allow them to create a spatial view for different layers. I have define a set of styles fitting the display I want to give. I would like to define these styles to the view automatically every-time a new view is created. I am currently using QGIS 2.14, PostGIS 2.3, PostgreSQL 9.5 and Python 3 with the psycopg2 library.

I thought about simply populating the layer_style table in the database, but without success.

Does anyone know how to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized that I made a simple little mistake in my piece of code which were not fulfilling properly the field f_table_schema, hence stopping my first idea to work. In case it can be of any help anyway, I just included and `INSERT INTO public.layer_styles` and inserted the desired values taken from a previous tuple in this table.

Answer (score 3):

you would do the following: Worked for me inside my plugin for QGIS 2.14.15:

- get the current layer:

  layer = iface.activeLayer()
- apply the qml file

  layer.loadNamedStyle("C\path\to\your\style\style.qml")
- load the layer afterwords

and this should work. I store them in a folder inside the plugin folder.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that soon. However I would prefer to not have to store the syle locally, that way every new user opening the view would have the same style displayed, that's why I thought more to automatize the "Save style to database (define as default style)" function available in QGIS, I don't really understand how this function works (nor the structure of the qml that is stored).

Comment: @GuiOmClair the qml file is in xml format ( just open one in notpad++ or any other text editor). what i meant by "store inside the plugin folder" is, that you could ship your plugin with a folder which already contains your default styles and allow the user to overwrite them

Comment: I understand. About the qml I meant I didn't take time to explore its structure yet, and about the storing in the plugin, I'd say that it is going in opposite direction than the idea of a DB to store datas, even a style, locally. In any case I really would like a storing in the DB which would make that a change in the style would be applied for every user. In this regard it should be possible to fetch the qml from the DB instead of from the local folder.

Comment: in that case I missunderstood you my bad!